# looping this to get all values to display instead of just displaying the last one(zipcode)

Tags: html, validation, user-input, getelementbyid

```
function ViewInput() {

  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("shippingaddress").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("country").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("city").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("state").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("cardnumber").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("securitycode").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("expirationdate").value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: [There you go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Answer (score 0):

Just append the new content, do not override it.

```js
function ViewInput() {
    var display = document.getElementById('display');

    display.innerHTML = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("shippingaddress").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("country").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("city").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("state").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("phonenumber").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("cardnumber").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("securitycode").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("expirationdate").value;
    display.innerHTML += document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
}
```